# QPushButton: how to make it just small enough to show it's text only

Tags: qt4

[image: 4 QPushButtons]

I have these pushbuttons and I have tried to minimize their sizes, but they refuse to go any smaller. They are all in a QHBoxLayout.
Can I shrink them to just show the +, the -, the <-> and the EC texts?

On the layout:

```
->setSpacing(1);
->setContentsMargins(1,1,1,1);
->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
```

On the buttons themselves:

```
->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
```

When adding the buttons to the layout:

```
->addWidget(button, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your buttons a little smaller by removing the padding on the buttons using style sheets.

```
ui->myPushButton->setStyleSheet( "padding: 0px;" );
```

I would however **strongly** advise against using incredibly small buttons. As per [Fitt's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts's_law), the smaller a button is, the longer it takes for the User to move their cursor to within the bounds of the button, and the more likely they'll miss and click a neighboring element (made even more likely as there's no padding between the buttons in your example). This leads to user frustration, which is never a good thing.

Comment: So what would you then advise to checkboxes or radiobuttons? They are generally even smaller. How would they fit into Fitt's Law?

Comment: This stack overflow page has hundreds if not thousands of little links all over the place. Even your answer has a link to the wiki article for Fitt's Law. Surely OP's buttons would be roughly the same size of these links? Yet - I never become frustrated when using a website like this. It seems like your advice is not realistic.